# Apply different styles depending on user theme

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application in which I change the default styles a bit, to add some common padding or margin, or something like that. I usually do that either in the `Window.Resources` or in some resource dictionary I either load in the window’s or application’s resources. An example style could be this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
</Style>
```

So far so good. Note though that I am changing a default component, not a user component.

Today I noticed that the *Aero2* theme that is used in Windows 8 comes with a few different standard styles than I am used to from Windows 7’s *Aero* theme. Unfortunately I was not really able to make a generic style that would just work in both.

So, I want to be able to specify different styles, depending on which theme the user is using. For example, if the user is using *Aero*, I want to load `Aero-styles.xaml`, and if it’s *Aero2* on Windows 8, I want to load `Aero2-styles.xaml` instead.

I was hoping this would be possible by using the *Themes* directory and providing `Aero.NormalColor.xaml` and `Aero2.NormalColor.xaml`. Unfortunately that seems to only work for *custom* controls, but not the built-in controls. It also does not make the available keys available to be used as a static/dynamic reference.

Is there a way to do this? To provide maybe a base resource dictionary that contains customizations and then another theme-dependent dictionary with minor adjustments to the used theme?

Comment: Related question on MSDN, unfortunately without a clear answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9cb36dc-bc85-45a8-80b2-56dbfe24c5c9/how-to-apply-styles-based-on-current-theme

Answer (score -1):

Detect theme on startup (before any UI is loaded), and dynamically add appropriate ResourceDictionary to Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries.
This worked for me.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to do this? Especially on the *theme-detection* part? All solutions I have found so far were pretty hacky or not able to detect “Aero2” for Windows 8.